# Is every matrix either positive or negative definite?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I think the answer is YES.

My question boils down to this: Is there a matrix that is neither positive nor negative definite?

Comment: Google "indefinite matrices".

Comment: Neither positive definite nor negative definite.

Answer (score 4):

For example

$$\begin{pmatrix}-1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\ldots$$

is indefinite